# Integration Workflow Error in CRM 2016 Online

Tags: crm, docusignapi

When using  the custom workflows (integration workflow) of the DocuSign to a CRM Online, I encountered an error about a null value.

[image]

I have followed the sequence correctly *(CreateEnvelop, AddDocument, AddRecipients then GetSignature)* but I still get the error. I think the workflows were part of the solution so we don't have access to the codes unless we decompile it - which is something we don't want to do. We even thought it might be illegal since it's not our dll.

How can we resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the DocuSign base solution are you currently running? The base solution is separate from the workflow solution, and it's generally recommended that you install the latest version of that base solution along side the workflow solution.

A few things can cause this issue:

1. A refresh token that is set to null in your DocuSign configuration.  This is the most likely problem.  Go to "DocuSign Config" in the Settings dropdown on the sitemap, and open up the active DocuSign configuration.  When it loads, you'll see a "Linked to O365" field:  click the "refresh" link.  This will ensure a token is created and that the workflow solution can get to it.
2. An invalid envelope ID.  Make sure that the workflow is configured correctly and the envelope information is successfully getting passed to the AddDocument activity.
3. The entity or entity ID is not available to the workflow activity.  The AddDocument activity needs to know this so it can connect to the entity in question to retrieve the note attachment(s).  This could potentially happen if instead of setting up a workflow, you setup a custom action and did not assign it to an entity.

If none of these things help resolve the issue, feel free to reach out to DocuSign tech support and we'll help you diagnose the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew. I tried to do the refresh of the "Linked to O365", but I encountered an error. The second one that you want me to do, the configuration of the envelop was blank as what it said on the DocuSign PDF, it will just use the default configuration. For the entity ID, I made a workflow that was assigned to the entity where the files were attached.

Comment: DocuSign Solution Version: 4.1.1.0
DocusignWorkflow Solution Version: 1.0

Comment: Hi Andrew. The first option just worked. I don't know why it didn't work a while ago but now it is working. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Glad it worked!  Please feel free to get in contact with us if you have any more issues.